# Get all filenames inside a directory on FTP [Python]

Tags: python, ftp, filenames, ftplib

Today I ran into a big problem and because I'm fairly new with Python I'm really going to need to ask for help.

I've managed to connect to my FTP and login correctly.

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.lala.com', 'username', 'pass')
```

As a second step I move into the dir that I'd like:

```
ftp.cwd("dirName")
```

But then I run stuck.. I now need to get all the filenames in a string / array / list / .. format to be able to use all those names. I've tried OS, glob, .. but this doesn't seem to work in any way.
Any thoughts please? I would need to get every filename inside the dir that I want and also any directories/files within the wanted dir.

I somehow need to change this

```
for fileName in glob.glob("*.*"):
    self.out(fileName)
```

to go to the path ftp.lala.com/myDir/ and then get all the filenames out (also if there is a folder inside myDir)

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome!
Thanks
Yenthe

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
contents = ftp.retrlines('LIST')  # List CWD contents securely.
```

Or:

```
try:
    files = ftp.nlst()
except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
    if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
        print("No files in this directory.")
else:
    raise
```

`contents` is now a list of items within that directory that you can call.

Comment: Due to the framework and platform that I use I can't use this one sadly. For 99% of the people this would in fact be good yes, but I need another way! Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: AWESOME! That in fact is a fix :) Now, would you also know a way to get all filenames if there are files inside a directory where is another directory?
So 
Dir to search : file.css, file.html, file.txt, directory
How can I get the files within the directory that is inside the dir I search for? By the way, awesome programming knowledge for your age.

Comment: Fair enough! You've solved the main problem so I've accepted the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I get all path/files with this code:

```
import ftplib

server= ftplib.FTP_TLS('YOUR FTP ADRESS','USER','PASSWORD')
print("CONNECTED TO FTP")

files = server.nlst('your FTP folder path')
print(files)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("hostname")
ftp.login("username", "password")
ftp.cwd("foldername")
files = ftp.nlst()
print(files)
```